# Merge [guzzlehttp] into [guzzle]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Let's merge/alias [guzzlehttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guzzlehttp) (in)to [guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guzzle). Or the other way around, that doesn't matter to me.

The description of [guzzlehttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guzzlehttp) already says:

> it's a duplicate tag, use [guzzle] instead

Comment: `[guzzle]` should probably be the main tag purely based on the repo name of the project or even `[guzzlephp]` as per the site name.